# Aplicar estilo CSS a un radio button seleccionado (checked) label

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, radiobutton

Tengo un problema trabajando con CSS y HTML: mediante propiedades CSS cambié el estilo de los radios con los que estoy trabajando, pero el problema que tengo es que no se seleccionan, a esto me refiero que no se queda seleccionado el botón que cree (que es un radio).

Éste es el código CSS relacionado:

```
#pregunta input[type=radio]{
     display: none;
}

#pregunta label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #FAE3BB;
  color: #4C3000;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  min-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#pregunta label:hover {
  background: #EBBB67;
}

#pregunta input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background: #CB8306;
  color: #FAFAFA;

}
```

Y aquí está el código en cuestión (también disponible en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JuanJose/pen/pwLGXB):

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font: 16px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  display: table;
}

body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#examen {
  margin: -44px 50px 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
}

#examen h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 44px;
}

#pregunta {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
}

#pregunta h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#pregunta input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

#pregunta label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #FAE3BB;
  color: #4C3000;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  min-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#pregunta label:hover {
  background: #EBBB67;
}

#pregunta input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background: #CB8306;
  color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="examen">
    <h1 id="nombrePregunta"> </h1>
    <div id="pregunta">
      <label for="pregunta1">pregunta1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" value="pregunta1">
      <label for="pregunta2">pregunta2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pregunta2" value="pregunta2">
      <label for="pregunta3">pregunta3</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pregunta3" value="pregunta3">
      <label for="pregunta4">pregunta4</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pregunta4" value="pregunta4">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en el código:

1. Los radios no tienen `id` y todos tienen diferente `name`. Esto es importante porque los `label` apuntan al `id` de los campos objetivo y ahora mismo ninguno tiene ID. Además, como todos tienen diferente `name`, una vez marcados no se desmarcarán nunca.
2. Como decía, los `label` deben apuntar al `id` y no al `name` como apuntan ahora.
3. Tienes los `label` delante de los `checkboxes` pero luego en el CSS indicas que los `checkbox` deberían delante de los `label` (en esta regla: `#pregunta input[type=radio]:checked + label`). Esto llevaría a confusiones porque se marcaría la respuesta siguiente en lugar de la que pulsaste.

Añadiendo IDs, cambiando a un `name` común y corrigiendo el orden del HTML para que sea `checkbox` y luego `label` ya funciona:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font: 16px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  display: table;
}

body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#examen {
  margin: -44px 50px 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
}

#examen h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 44px;
}

#pregunta {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
}

#pregunta h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#pregunta input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

#pregunta label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #FAE3BB;
  color: #4C3000;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  min-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#pregunta label:hover {
  background: #EBBB67;
}

#pregunta input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background: #CB8306;
  color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="examen">
    <h1 id="nombrePregunta"> </h1>
    <div id="pregunta">
      <input type="radio" name="pregunta" value="pregunta1" id="pregunta1">
      <label for="pregunta1">pregunta1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pregunta" value="pregunta2" id="pregunta2">
      <label for="pregunta2">pregunta2</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pregunta" value="pregunta3" id="pregunta3">
      <label for="pregunta3">pregunta3</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pregunta" value="pregunta4" id="pregunta4">
      <label for="pregunta4">pregunta4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Amigos muchas gracias, creo que esta es la respuesta correcta, no sabia si tenia que utilizar Javascript o algún otro lenguaje .. Muchas gracias.